# Annoying auto-saving when a property is modified

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, netbeans-7, save

since this morning NetBeans (7.2.1) autosaves every change to a swing component property. Its pretty annoying, because NetBeans collapses all nodes and so deselect the component I were changing.

More detailed description:

- NetBeans 7.2 (running in Mac OS)
- "Design" view
- When I select a component, it gets selected in the navigator view (by default on the left) and all parent nodes are expanded.
- Now I can either rightclick->properties or use the properties view (by default on the right).

When I make some changes and hit OK, NetBeans now (didnt do before and I use 7.2 since release) autosaves the complete project, collapsing all nodes in the navigator view. 
Now, selecting a component in the design view is not much of a problem. However I use the navigator view to scroll up and down with arrow keys, rename components, or do changes in the properties view. With the new behaviour, I have to expand the complete tree all over again and its annoying.

Anyone have an idea what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried to uninstall/reinstall the whole thing, as well as trying with previous Netbeans versions.